# GetProcessImageFileNameA throwing ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: java, windows, jna

I'm using JNA to call `GetProcessImageFileNameA` from Kernel32 but every time I run the program I get a random result, either I get ERROR_SUCCESS or ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

```java
Memory processName = new Memory(1024);
IntByReference read = new IntByReference(1024);
psapi.GetProcessImageFileNameA(handle, processName, read);

System.out.println(processName.getString(0));
System.out.println(kernel32.GetLastError());
```

The handle is valid every time and has nothing to do with the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function mapping for the third parameter is `DWORD nSize`.  A `DWORD` can be directly mapped to a (4-byte) `int`.

You have passed an `IntByReference` which is a pointer to an `int`.

Try

```java
int read = 1024;
```

Comment: I have tried that before with no luck, but you made me try to pass an Integer instead, and now it works, thanks!